# Eclipse - an error as occurred see the log file

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

So I was using eclipse and all of a sudden it got stuck and when I tried reopening it this error popped up and eclipse won't open.

here the latest of the log file:

> !SESSION 2016-10-18 21:53:30.325
>   ----------------------------------------------- eclipse.buildId=4.6.0.I20160606-1100 java.version=1.8.0_101
>   java.vendor=Oracle Corporation BootLoader constants: OS=win32,
>   ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US Framework arguments:  -product
>   org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product Command-line arguments:  -os
>   win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product
>   org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
>
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2016-10-18 21:53:32.667 !MESSAGE An error
>   occurred while automatically activating bundle
>   org.eclipse.core.resources (85). !STACK 0
>   org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in
>   org.eclipse.core.resources.ResourcesPlugin.start() of bundle
>   org.eclipse.core.resources.   at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:795)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:724)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.startWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:932)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$EquinoxModule.startWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:309)
>     at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:581)   at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:449)  at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:470)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.hooks.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:529)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.findLocalClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:325)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:334)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.sources.SingleSourcePackage.loadClass(SingleSourcePackage.java:36)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:407)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:361)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:353)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:161)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)  at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:139)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:673)  at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:610)     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1519) Caused by:
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ResourceException: Incompatible
>   file format. Workspace was saved with an incompatible version: 0.     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.WorkspaceTreeReader.getReader(WorkspaceTreeReader.java:59)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.WorkspaceTreeReader.getReader(WorkspaceTreeReader.java:67)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.SaveManager.restoreTree(SaveManager.java:1056)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.SaveManager.restore(SaveManager.java:719)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.SaveManager.startup(SaveManager.java:1587)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.startup(Workspace.java:2399)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.open(Workspace.java:2156)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.resources.ResourcesPlugin.start(ResourcesPlugin.java:464)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:774)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:1)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:767)
>     ... 29 more Root exception:
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ResourceException: Incompatible
>   file format. Workspace was saved with an incompatible version: 0.     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.WorkspaceTreeReader.getReader(WorkspaceTreeReader.java:59)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.WorkspaceTreeReader.getReader(WorkspaceTreeReader.java:67)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.SaveManager.restoreTree(SaveManager.java:1056)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.SaveManager.restore(SaveManager.java:719)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.SaveManager.startup(SaveManager.java:1587)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.startup(Workspace.java:2399)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.open(Workspace.java:2156)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.resources.ResourcesPlugin.start(ResourcesPlugin.java:464)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:774)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:1)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:767)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:724)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.startWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:932)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$EquinoxModule.startWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:309)
>     at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:581)   at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:449)  at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:470)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.hooks.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:529)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.findLocalClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:325)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:334)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.sources.SingleSourcePackage.loadClass(SingleSourcePackage.java:36)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:407)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:361)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:353)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:161)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)  at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:139)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:673)  at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:610)     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1519)
>
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2016-10-18 21:53:32.682 !MESSAGE
>   Application error !STACK 1 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/eclipse/core/resources/IContainer     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:139)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:673)  at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:610)     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1519) Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: An error occurred while
>   automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.core.resources (85).  at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.hooks.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:116)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:529)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.findLocalClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:325)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:334)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.sources.SingleSourcePackage.loadClass(SingleSourcePackage.java:36)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:407)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:361)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:353)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:161)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)  ... 13 more
>   Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in
>   org.eclipse.core.resources.ResourcesPlugin.start() of bundle
>   org.eclipse.core.resources.   at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:795)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:724)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.startWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:932)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$EquinoxModule.startWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:309)
>     at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:581)   at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:449)  at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:470)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.hooks.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:107)
>     ... 22 more Caused by:
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ResourceException: Incompatible
>   file format. Workspace was saved with an incompatible version: 0.     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.WorkspaceTreeReader.getReader(WorkspaceTreeReader.java:59)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.WorkspaceTreeReader.getReader(WorkspaceTreeReader.java:67)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.SaveManager.restoreTree(SaveManager.java:1056)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.SaveManager.restore(SaveManager.java:719)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.SaveManager.startup(SaveManager.java:1587)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.startup(Workspace.java:2399)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.open(Workspace.java:2156)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.resources.ResourcesPlugin.start(ResourcesPlugin.java:464)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:774)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:1)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:767)
>     ... 29 more

Comment: did you install any plugin recently?

Comment: @lsiva I didn't, I tried to run a program when it couldn't be compiled  but I think eclipse was pretty much stuck beforehand as well. either way that shouldn't cause that problem

Comment: Sorting out eclipse issue is tough, instead download a fresh copy of eclipse and use it.